# Character x,y in password - LoadRunner

Tags: c, load-testing, performance-testing, loadrunner

I'm doing a load test for a sign in page where the user needs to input 2 characters of their password.

I've created an array of characters to say 'password1'.

Using correlation parameters I'm able to get the character number required. What I'm now trying to do is get the character number and match the array i.e. -

`Character 1 is required, it will scan the array and bring back char[0].`

`Character 2 is required, it will scan the array and bring back char[1] etc.`

I was thinking of doing a for loop to go through the array and determine where in the array a character is stored. I can't think how to initiate this for loop:

`char1 = (char1-1);`

`char2 = (char2-1);`

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    lr_output_message("%s",p[i]);
    if (p[i] == p[char1]){
        char1 = p[i];
    }
}
```

The for loop works but it equals 115 (s in ASCII), I need a way of converting the value to a character, but I keep getting memory violations.

Sorry if I've over-complicated this issue, but my head has been lost trying to think about how to solve a seemingly easy problem. No doubt some of you will look at it a different way and tell me I've over-complicated it a significant amount!

Answer (score 0):

Closed - worked it out.

Using these buffers instead of for loop.

`buf[0] = char1a;`

`buf[1] = ‘\0’;`

`buf2[0] = char2a;`

`buf2[1] = ‘\0’;`